# PHP, how to parse a "clean url"

Tags: php, parsing, url

I have this url:
http://www.example.com/media/var10/var20/something/morestuff

I need to get var10, var20 something and morestuff.

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/explode

Comment: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=parse+url+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=CxLaU-6LMuaH8QeAtYGIDg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is quite simple.

1. Strip the the http:// from the URL using the substring function. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_substr.asp for more information on substr
2. Use explode() to split the url into an array of strings. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp for more information on explode.

you can iterate through the array that explode returns to get all the parts of the url you want.

Comment: Step 1 isn't required

Comment: Rather than w3schools, why not link to the official PHP manual: http://php.net/substr, http://php.net/explode

Comment: IMSoP, because he seemed like a beginner, I figured w3schools provides easier to read documentation for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

The following code will extract the parts of the path from the URL into an array and print it.

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/media/var10/var20/something/morestuff';

$urlPathParts = explode('/', ltrim(parse_url($url,  PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));

print_r($urlPathParts);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/media/var10/var20/something/morestuff';
$url_parts = parse_url($url);
$path_parts = explode('/', trim($url_parts['path'], '/'));
var_dump($path_parts);
```

will output:

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(5) "media"
  [1] =>
  string(5) "var10"
  [2] =>
  string(5) "var20"
  [3] =>
  string(9) "something"
  [4] =>
  string(9) "morestuff"
}
```

Just access the array indexes for the parts you want.